# $\sqrt{a} +\sqrt{b} = 20$. What is the maximum value of $a-5b$?

Tags: calculus

It is given that  $$\sqrt{a} +\sqrt{b} = 20$$
Where a and b are real numbers.

What is the maximum value of $a-5b$?

Comment: You should have seen problems like this.  Solve for $b$ as a function of $a$, plug that in so $a-5b$ is just a function of $a$, take the derivative, set to zero...  Number theory refers to integers, while your variables are presumably real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\sqrt{b}=20-\sqrt{a}$$
$$b=(20-\sqrt{a})^2=400-40\sqrt{a}+a$$
$$a-5b=a-5(400-40\sqrt{a}+a)=-4a+200\sqrt{a}-2000$$

$$\frac{d}{da}(a-5b)=-4+\frac{100}{\sqrt{a}}$$

Since $\sqrt{a}<20$,

$$\frac{d}{da}(a-5b)>0$$

Hence, $a-5b$ is maximum when $a$ is maximum, viz., when $a=400$ (and $b=0$)

Hence, the maximum value of $a-5b$ is $400$.

Comment: There's a problem : you say that the maximum value is 500, but that would be attained for $a=25^2$. And this would imply $\sqrt{b} = -5$

Comment: OK thx, let me edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

You've not specified any constraints. I'll also assume the square root symbol has the conventional meaning of the non-negative root. $a- 5b$ is maximised when $a$ is maximal and $b$ is minimal. Minimum value of $b$ that allows a real square root is $0$. So maximal $a - 5b = a = 400$.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG let $a=400\sin^2x,b=400\cos^2x$

$a-5b=200(2\sin^2x-5\cdot2\cos^2x)=200\{1-\cos2x-5(1+\cos2x)\}$

$=-200(4+6\cos2x)$

We need to minimize $4+6\cos2x$

$\cos2x\ge-1\iff4+6\cos2x\ge-2$ which occurs if $x=(2n+1)\dfrac\pi2$

Comment: WLOG? I have yet to encounter that one

Comment: @zz20s,  Please Google, u'll find too many links:)